# XCode wants me to specify a className when creating a new instance of a PFObject subclass

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am using XCode 6.3.1 with Parse 1.7.2.
I defined the following PFObject subclass:

```
class MyClass: PFObject, PFSubclassing {
    @NSManaged var date:NSDate!
    @NSManaged var title:String!
    @NSManaged var device:String!
    @NSManaged var subscribers:NSArray!
    @NSManaged var numberOfPictures:NSNumber!

    override class func initialize() {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            self.registerSubclass()
        }
    } 

    static func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "MyClass"
    }
}
```

But when I try to instantiate this class later on in some other code:

```
var myObject = MyClass()
```

The compiler gives me an error, saying that I should specify a className parameter to the MyClass constructor.
Did I miss something here?

Comment: FYI, apparently it's a bug in Parse SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/774396032658665/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse SDK 1.7.3 seems to solve this bug.

Answer (score 0):

The way you handle did not give it a class name when you initialize, it should be something like this:

```
var myObject = MyClass("MyClass")
```

Comment: But why should I do that? Why should I specify the class name as a parameter to the constructor? I never had to do that before.

Comment: If not, how can the Parse class know which table you are handling for? You must specify the class name somewhere before. Otherwise, you just get an object without class name and Parse does not know which table is related.

Comment: But normally the SDK should know which table it uses based on the class name (MyClass) and the return value of parseClassName in MyClass.

Comment: No matter you fetch using PFQuery or create PFObject, you still need to specify the class name first. Otherwise, SDK does not know which table you want to deal with?

Comment: No, here I'm not creating a PFObject, I'm creating a MyClass that is a subclass of PFObject with a declaration to help Parse automatically link it with the right table. It's always worked like that, I never needed to specify the class name when creating an instance of a subclass of PFObject. cf. the documentation here: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-subclassing-pfobject